# ANDROID Navigation Component + BottomNavigationView with backstack

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-graph, android-bottomnavigationview

I want use navigation component from jetpack in my app. I could find base examples work of nav component + bottom view navigation,below I showed how I implemented using these examples. But its works uncorrect for me - its recreate fragments when switching between tabs.
But i found navigatiom extension from google https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample/NavigationExtensions.kt but its too doesnt works.I do everything according to the instructions on my activity:

```
    private fun setupBottomNavigationBar() {
            val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.nav_bottom)

            val navGraphIds = listOf(
                R.navigation.home_nav,
                R.navigation.search_nav,
                R.navigation.scheduled_nav,
                R.navigation.profile_nav
            )

            val controller = bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(
                navGraphIds,
                supportFragmentManager,
                R.id.nav_host_container,
                intent
            )

            controller.observe(this, Observer { navController ->
                setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
            })
            currentNavController = controller
        }
```

I call this function in onCreate (when savedInstanceState == null) and in onRestoreInstanceState
my layout file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".app.ui.main.MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nav_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/back_bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bot_nav_menu"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bot_navigation_items"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bot_navigation_items"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is exactly the same code as in the example
But this does not work, fragments are not displayed, and if setupItemReselected (graphIdToTagMap, fragmentManager) is installed in the Navigation Extention, an error is caused in this function on the line val `selectedFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag (newlySelectedItemTag)`
with error `kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment`, so fragment manager cant find fragment by tag (?)
Please help me guys, I research this problem second day!

Answer (score 2):

Today, I was facing the problem that I have a bottom navigation and  respectively navigations. But fragments were not being changed on clicking bottom tabs. And then I solved the problem by giving same ID to navigation graph as I set in menu items. And this worked for me. And I got this clue with comment of @Ильмир Шагабиев as mentioned in the answer. Posting it as an answer because at firs time I did not notice this in comment. And after spending some time I came back to the same post and went through all comments.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set your `FragmentContainerView`, you need to do as follow:

```xml
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_container"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
```

Have a look at this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/), you can replace `fragment` by `FragmentcontainerView` and it'll work out.

In case the xml isn't fixing your issue can you post your `nav_graph` ?

Comment: the solution was to assign the same identifiers for the menu items on "bot_nav_menu" file  as the names of the xml navigation files. OMG!

Comment: Yeah that's why I asked for your `nav_graph` :p

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem.
As described [here](https://proandroiddev.com/step-by-step-to-bottom-navigation-with-jetpacks-navigation-component-and-multiple-nav-graphs-271c05af1dd3) you have to make sure that the IDs of the bottom navigation menu items are identical to those in the navigation graphs. So in your case the bottom navigation menu should look similar to this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/home_nav"
        android:icon="..."
        android:title="..." />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search_nav"
        android:icon="..."
        android:title="..." />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/scheduled_nav"
        android:icon="..."
        android:title="..." />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/profile_nav"
        android:icon="..."
        android:title="..." />

</menu>
```